# How create a table on DynamoDB with a GlobalSecondaryIndexes in local?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I DynamoDB install locally on Windows 7.
My project is a Node.js(0.12.0) and I use aws-sdk.

Version DynamoDB : 2012-08-10

This work ->

```
dynamodb.createTable({
TableName: 'Users',
AttributeDefinitions: [{AttributeName: 'userId', AttributeType: 'S'}],
KeySchema: [{AttributeName: 'userId', KeyType: 'HASH'}],
ProvisionedThroughput: {
    'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
    'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
}
}, function () {
    ...
});
```

This don't work ->

```
dynamodb.createTable({
TableName: 'Users',
AttributeDefinitions: [{AttributeName: 'userId', AttributeType: 'S'}],
KeySchema: [{AttributeName: 'userId', KeyType: 'HASH'}],
ProvisionedThroughput: {
    'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
    'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
},
GlobalSecondaryIndexes: [
    {
        IndexName: 'longitudeUserIndex',
        KeySchema: [
            {
                AttributeName: 'userId',
                KeyType: 'HASH'
            },
            {
                AttributeName: 'longitude',
                KeyType: 'RANGE'
            }
        ],
        Projection: {
            NonKeyAttributes: [
            ],
            ProjectionType: 'KEYS_ONLY'
        },
        ProvisionedThroughput: {
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
        }
    }
]
}, function () {
    ...
});
```

Doc DynamoDB Javascript : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#createTable-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem.

I added in AttributeDefinitions longitude.

```
AttributeDefinitions: [{AttributeName: 'userId', AttributeType: 'S'}, {AttributeName: 'longitude', AttributeType: 'N'}]
```